# Windows 7 sees 100% free space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, defragment

I installed Windows 7 Ultimate and it worked well. But I realized that I needed Windows 7 Professional. I installed the new edition. Then I tried to defragment my HDD (I use Ashampoo Winoptimizer 7), but I couldn't see my D: partition. Windows Disk Management recognized that drive D: has 100% free space. In Explorer I see the files on it and I can use it like my other partitions.

**Why can't Windows Disk Management see that my D: drive isn't just free space?**

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate contains all the features of Professional thus there is no reason to downgrade. Windows does not have "partition magic". Besides the useless information your question is confusing... If my answer doesn't help you, try to make your question more clear.

Comment: English? (15 chars)

Comment: This question was in fact re-asked, rephrased as requested in the comments, [here, a day later](http://superuser.com/questions/157769/free-space-detection-bugs).

Comment: I've just corrected the English in this question. What use is a question if no one can understand it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Back up your Important data first
2. Run chkdsk on the partition with free space problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try a free defragmentation program like [MyDefrag](http://mydefrag.com/) to see if the same problem occurs there.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention that MyDefrag uses the Windows Defragmentation API.

Comment: Try Defraggler instead

Comment: Bobby, those things are mentioned on the site and he should just try an alternative to see if it occurs there. D'Arvit, if he can see the files using Windows, then a defragmentation program that uses the Windows Defragmentation API will see the same and thus see it.